# Opcenter issue about secondary constraints (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, aps

I work at a company that is in APS. I am currently trying to move older configuration to a new version of Opcenter. The problem I have is when I try to import Specific data for secondary constraints it throws an exception.
PreactorObj.WriteField,WriteField

As I said I am trying to move configuration and I am not able to figure out the reason behind this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjhhA.png)
I am not able to figure out the reason as it works on older configuration

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.